# How do I escape while loop when I have N amount of inputs?

Tags: c, input, while-loop, stdin

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input;
    
    int i=0;
    while (1){
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("%d input:%d\n", i, input);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Stdin Inputs:
10
65
100
30
95
.
.
.

Is there a way to stop the code and escape from while loop after hitting the last Input?
Amount of Inputs can be N.

edition) Is there a way to calculate the amount of Stdin Inputs? This is my major question.

Comment: Maybe consider using a `for` loop? Or, failing that, use the `break` statement.

Comment: How do you identify the "last input"? There arfew ways to "escape" it. You have the loop condition, or you have the `break` keyword

Comment: I do want to use the break, but there's N amount of inputs. I don't know if there's a way to know how many inputs I have

Comment: You already have the `i` counter, so your question isn't clear.

Comment: i counter was to just to see my output counts on the code

Comment: So why do you think you can't use it for other purposes? Like comparing to `N` and breaking. I would use the `for` loop instead though, because it is there just for the cases like this.

Comment: how can I compare i with N ? all we know is that N is the last input. is there a way to get the amount of the input on the code?

Comment: You should rewrite your question, stating explicitly what you mean by N and also giving the sample inputs. Currently it sounds like you want to read exactly N inputs, while N is known. But reading your comments it sounds differently.

Comment: What about `while (scanf("%d",&input) == 1) {`? That will read as many values as the file has

Comment: Thanks Craig Estey, that was what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are reading an input that has an EOF (End of file)?
In that case you should stop when receiving EOF

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  int input;
  int i = 0;
  while (scanf("%d", &input) != EOF){
    printf("%d input:%d\n", i, input);
    i++;
  }
  printf("End\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you can do a program that first reads N and then iterate N time

```
int main(void)
{
  int input;
  int i = 0;
  int n = 0;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("%d input:%d\n", i, input);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input;
    
    int i=0;
    while (1){
        scanf("%d", &input);
        printf("%d input:%d\n", i, input);
        i++;
        if (i >= 5) break; //change 5 to your desired amount of inputs
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of typing out range of i manually, is there a way to get amount of stdin inputs and place it in the range; so that range automatically changes depending on the input amount

Comment: Sadly, no.
If you want you can implement an Library. That would overcomplicate everything, but if you have to go that way, do it.

I would not try to make everything perfect. If it works, do it.